# Django field name conflicts on save

Tags: python, django

I have a template which displays a form with data from 2 models. Both models contain an attribute called "name". The issue is that when I save, the incorrect value for "name" from the form is saved for appuser model. How can I get the correct values for each of the 2 forms for the "name" field please?

**View see (#ISSUE)**

```
    class FarmCreateView(CreateView):
        template_name = 'directory/farm_registration.html'
        model = Appuser
        success_url = '/'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(FarmCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['farm'] = FarmForm()
            context['appuser'] = FarmUserCreateForm()
            return context

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            farm_form = FarmForm(self.request.POST)
            appuser_form = FarmUserCreateForm(self.request.POST)

            if farm_form.is_valid() and appuser_form.is_valid():
                # Save the appuser
                new_user = appuser_form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.name = appuser_form.cleaned_data.get('name') 

# ISSUE I would expect the line above to return the name from the
# appuser_form, but instead it return the name from the farm_form
                new_user.save()

                # Save the farm
                new_farm = farm_form.save(commit=False)
                new_farm.appuser = new_user; 
                new_farm.save()
                farm_form.save_m2m() # This is needed because we 
# initially save with commit=false - it's just the way django works

                # Log user in after registration
                new_user_login = authenticate(email=request.POST['email'], 
                   password=request.POST['password'])
                login(request, new_user_login)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return render_to_response('directory/farm_registration.html', {'farm': 
                   farm_form, 'appuser': appuser_form}, 
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Template extract**

```
<div class="pure-g">
   <div class="pure-u-1-2 {{appuser.name.css_classes}}" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">{{appuser.name}}</div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-2 {{appuser.surname.css_classes}}"><div style="float:right;">{{appuser.surname}}</div></div>
 <div class="pure-u-1-2 {{appuser.email.css_classes}}" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">{{appuser.email}}</div>
   <div class="pure-u-1-2 {{appuser.phone_number.css_classes}}"><div style="float:right;">{{appuser.phone_number}}</div></div>
   <div class="pure-u-1-2 {{appuser.password.css_classes}}" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">{{appuser.password}}</div>
   <div class="pure-u-1-2 {{appuser.password1.css_classes}}"><div style="float:right;">{{appuser.password1}}</div></div>
</div>
 <!-- Farm Info -->
<div style="height:28px; position:relative; text-align:center; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:1px; margin-right:1px">
 <div class="page_section_strikethrough"></div>    
  <div class="page_section_heading" style="background:rgb(246,246,246)">FARM INFO</div>
 </div>
  <div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1-1 {{farm.name.css_classes}}" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">{{farm.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Use `prefix` in the form, like this `context['farm'] = FarmForm(prefix="farm_form")` and `FarmUserCreateForm(prefix='farm_user_create')`

Comment: @AmitYadav Thanks, that worked, if you give your comment as an answer I will accept

Comment: I am glad it worked, now you should read what prefix done to your form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prefix in the form, like this:

```
context['farm'] = FarmForm(prefix="farm_form")
context['appuser'] = FarmUserCreateForm(prefix='farm_user_create')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `name` attribute in the rendered forms, in particular those for the `{{ appuser.name }}` and `{{ farm.name }}` input elements.

I guess they are the same, because I don't think there is be namespacing going on inside the rendered template. Thus, there'll be two `<input name="name" ...>` elements, and upon `POST`, one will overwrite the other.

Hence when you're creating the bound forms inside the `post(...)` method, you fill both forms with the same name. You can verify the latter by printing the value of `self.request.POST` when running the development server: you should only see one `name` key.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I prevent/fix this?

Comment: Give them a different name in your form? Just rename the corresponding  attributes in your Form classes, to e.g. `appuser_name` and `farm_name`.